# Finding the residue of $(z^2+1)^{-1}$ at $i$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a rather simple question. We know that Res$(f,\alpha_k)$, where $\alpha_k$ is a pole of function $f\in\mathbb{C}$ is given by the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series expansion of $f$. In my particular case, the function $f$ is defined as

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}$$

now, with some crafty manipulation I got to this point:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{(z+i)-(z-i)}{(z+i)(z-i)}\right]$$
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}\right]$$

now because I'm trying to find the Laurent series expansion for $f$ in the neighbourhood of $i$, is it at this point sufficient to, without any further expansion, conclude that Res$(f,i)=\frac{1}{2i}$? Since, here, the coefficient of the first term inside the brackets $=a_{-1}$, or is this form of $f$ not conclusive of the value of $a_{-1}$?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or, alternatively, by recognizing the pole is a simple one, one can use the formula
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}f(z)=\lim_{z\to i}f(z)(z-i)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac1{(z+i)(z-i)}\cdot(z-i)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac1{z+i}=\frac1{2i}$$

In general, the residue of $f(z)$ at a $n$-th order pole $z=a$ is
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=a}f(z)=\frac1{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}f(z)(z-a)^n$$